# Concave function applied to equally distant points

Tags: convex-optimization

Is the next statement true?

Let $f$ be concave and $a \leq b \in dom(f)$. For any $c \geq 0$ such that $a+c, b+c \in dom(f)$ then
$$ f(b+c) - f(b) \leq f(a+c) - f(a) $$

If it is, how would you prove it?

Comment: You also need to assume $c \ge 0$.

Comment: What states Robert Israel is true. And it doesn't matter. You can assume c < 0 as well. What you are going to use is that the slopes cannot increase, remember that the slope and the direction of the points used are independent.

Comment: No, believe it or not multiplying an inequality by a negative number changes the direction of the inequality.

Comment: You are very right! I didn't take a look carefuly. Thank you! I'll correct my hypothesis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an easy way to show it directly from the definition of concavity.
Let $\theta = c/(c + b - a)$. We need $c\ge0$ so that $\theta \in [0,1]$. Then we have:
$$
\begin{aligned}
b   &=     \theta a + (1-\theta)(b+c)\\
a+c &= (1-\theta) a +    \theta (b+c)
\end{aligned}
$$
Then concavity of $f$ implies:
$$
\begin{aligned}
f(b)   &\ge     \theta f(a) + (1-\theta)f(b+c)\\
f(a+c) &\ge (1-\theta) f(a) +     \theta f(b+c)
\end{aligned}
$$
Adding the inequalities gives:
$$
f(b) + f(a+c) \ge f(a) + f(b+c) \quad \square
$$

On the other hand, if $c<0$, we can transform $a' = a+c$, $b' = b+c$, $c' = -c$ and apply the above inequality to the transformed variables.
$$
f(b') + f(a'+c') \ge f(a') + f(b'+c')\\
f(b+c) + f(a) \ge f(a+c) + f(b)
$$
So if $c<0$ the inequality is reversed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is true.  Note that (if necessary relabelling the points, and after dealing with some special cases) we can assume wlog that $a < a+c < b < b+c$. Concavity of $f$ implies that the slopes of the segments $[(a,f(a)), (a+c, f(a+c))]$, $[(a+c,f(a+c)), (b,f(b))]$ and $[(b,f(b)), (b+c,f(b+c))]$ are sorted in decreasing order.